# What data goes through Gateway connection to CosmosDB in Direct mode?

Tags: azure, database-connection, azure-cosmosdb

We're using a CosmosDB instance on Azure. It has multiple read replicas for each region we have, and a single write master.

I've noticed number of calls resulting in timeouts over time. We're using Direct connection mode, but looking at Azure metrics, I see long latencies for Gateway calls. So there must be some sort of calls/data that still uses the Gateway connection (perhaps some sort of metadata?) to talk to the DB.

Below is a screenshot of the Gateway latencies, as you can see some of the Southeast Asia calls take 10s of seconds, and result in the mentioned end to end timeouts.

[image]

So why some of the calls use the Gateway connection in Direct mode? And what is sent over the Gateway mode?

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in detail on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McZIQhZpvew

The SDK in Direct mode requires doing HTTP calls to Gateway to obtain:

- Account information (which regions are available, what is the consistency configuration, etc)
- Container information (what's the partition key definition?)
- Routing information (What are the TCP addresses to connect to for data plane operations)
- Any metadata resource operations (CRUD over Databases/Containers)

These are all considered metadata/management plane operations, and go through Gateway.
Data plane operations (CRUD/Query over Items/documents) are done through TCP.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and your informative video Matias. So the initial connections always goes through the gateway and the results of the account info, routing, etc is cached. Does that cache live forever? ie unless the connection is interrupted all the following calls will be made directly, right? If there is a network hiccup, does the SDK use the existing cache to reconnect? Also aside from network issues, can you think of why only one region keeps having latency hick ups for us?

Comment: The initial interactions (Gateway calls) are HTTP, the connections are maintained as long as the HttpClient in .NET decides so, but it's not a required from the SDK perspective, we are just doing a couple of HTTP calls and getting the information and storing that in the internal caches. These caches do get refreshed periodically (account information is refreshed every 5 minutes to pickup any new regions for example), and it would reuse the HTTP connections or create new ones if the previous ones were closed by the system.

Comment: Also these HTTP requests are not on the hot-path. Basically not in your data plane requests (unless it's the very first one after creating the client). Which means that the fact that you are seeing them in the chart does not mean it is impacting your data operations. If you do see slow data requests affecting your hourly P99 or P95, my recommendation would be to check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-dot-net-sdk-slow-request